# Jenkins node cannot run fastlane command - command not found

Tags: ios, macos, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, fastlane

We have a configured jenkins node (macOS) with SSH connection with user X. When trying to execute fastlane from the jenkins job (inside a shell executable build action) job output shows the below error.

> /var/folders/jg/mjb6fch147sdj76ynnrgnjrr0000gr/T/jenkins5916553296139089998.sh:
> line 3: fastlane: command not found

However when connecting to node (macOS) directly we can run the fastlane command.

The user is the same for the both cases.

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar error in ubuntu. Follow these checklist:

### Login user

- Get the **active user** during the execution with `whoami` or `id -un` in your jenkins script before the fastlane command
- Then go to your macos and open a shell, login with the **active user** and execute `fastlane`
- If you get the error: **command not found**, just install it in that shell instance for that user
- If using the active user, fastlane command exist, we are in problems. Share the results to help you

### PATH

Print the PATH variable inside of the jenkins script and then using the same user of previous paragraph, print the PATH in your mac. Compare them and share the results.

Just to try if they are different, you can override the PATH in the jenkins script with the value obtained in your mac. Something like this

```
echo "user:"
id -un
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/etc...

fastlane action get_version_number
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the user is the same in the above scenario you specified.

Comment: mmmm, Just to check if the agent is well configured, create a folder (jenkins script) and validate if the folder was created in your mac.

Comment: Check if PATH variable is the same in in the jenkins script nad in your mac shell

Comment: turns out that the PATH variable was incorrect, thank you!!

Comment: Thanks to you. I didn't know fastlane. It will help me in my unity 3d automations.